# TV Movie/Series about a man with higher pain tolerance

Tags: story-identification, tv

The flick was set in the future and everyone lived in a walled sealed city.  They had to go through decontamination and evaluation upon return from outside the city.  The team lead convinced the doctors to allow their "brute" to be allowed when it was determined that he was experiencing high levels of pain (or maybe temperature).  Anyway I think it was because he was a descendant of whatever they were afraid of outside.

It may have been part of Universal's Action Pack or something similar.  I don't believe it was TekWar.

I seem to remember them driving out of an underground entrance via a long ramp in a convoy formation.  One of the vehicles they drove looked a lot like this.
[image: F150 Flareside with camper]

This is a mind splinter for me because when the above vehicle came into production (1996) seemed to be after I saw the show, like de-ja-vue.

Edit-post answer:I was looking for the vehicle used and if possible its relation to production models.  The approved answer brought me to the image I wanted and so I marked it as such.

Comment: The answer is the same, true, but the question and key elements are very different.

Comment: Still, the accepted policy is to close as duplicates when the answer is the same on `story-identification` questions.

Comment: @Jammin4CO Nothing wrong with duplicates.  I think of it as simply tying all the questions with the same answer together, so it's easier to find them all for anyone looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be the failed TV pilot *Island City* (1994).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_City_(1994_film)):

> In the future, humanity develops a "fountain of youth" drug, but as many people around the world begin to take it, most begin to mutate into a barbaric proto-humanoid state. The few people immune to this side-effect of the drug band together and live in a futuristic city while the mutants live in the vast wasteland outside its gates. In an effort to save the human race and understand what went wrong, the city sends out research missions in fortified vehicles to bring back mutated humans for research, and to rescue healthy humans. The film focuses on one such squad of soldiers and scientists.

The "fortified vehicle" would be the truck you remember.  You can see it in the YouTube clip below.

I don't have a reference, but I also vaguely remember the half-mutant character being in constant pain.

Comment: This is exactly it!  100%  Thank you.  They must have gotten a prototype or concept vehicle for that.

Comment: I just noticed this was the case. If so, can you _change_ the answer somehow, so that this answer is not a complete copy of the other answer? You don't have to copy the whole of it, just the name, the synopsis, the video, and an attribution. (It doesn't matter because there's a duplicate question with the whole answer).

Comment: Looks good now ;)